# Error when importing flask.ext.markdown

Tags: python, flask, markdown, flask-flatpages

I have the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#coding: utf-8

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.flatpages import FlatPages
from flask.ext.markdown import Markdown
```

But when I try to run it, this error occurs : `ImportError: No module named flask.ext.markdown` whereas normally this module is existing.

Is there somebody who can say how to fix that ?

Comment: How do you know that the module exists? Have you installed it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need to install the flask-markdown plugin.

http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Markdown/

You can install this with pip:

```
pip install flask-markdown
```

alternatively:

```
easy_install flask-markdown
```

If it is already installed try downloading the source and importing it directly.

Answer (score 1):

That module hasn't been updated in over 3 years and uses the old flask extension API. There is a newer package called flask-markdown2.